# How to Integrate BIRT Chart Engine 4.6.0 into maven project

Tags: maven, charts, birt

I can't find it in maven central repository.
Documentation only include example with external jars.

Answer (score 0):

I includes birt runtime from maven repository. An other lib I put in local directory. That create warning, but It is ok for me:

```
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for TestWicketBIRTReport:TestWicketBIRTReport:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for org.eclipse.birt.chart.device.extension:org.eclipse.birt.chart.device.extension:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${project.basedir}/lib/org.eclipse.birt.chart.device.extension_4.6.0.v201606072122.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 65, column 25
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for org.eclipse.birt.chart.device.pdf:org.eclipse.birt.chart.device.pdf:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${project.basedir}/lib/org.eclipse.birt.chart.device.pdf_4.6.0.v201606072122.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 73, column 25
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for org.eclipse.birt.chart.device.svg:org.eclipse.birt.chart.device.svg:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${project.basedir}/lib/org.eclipse.birt.chart.device.svg_4.6.0.v201606072122.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 82, column 25
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for org.eclipse.birt.chart.chart-viewer:org.eclipse.birt.chart.chart-viewer:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${project.basedir}/lib/chart-viewer.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 91, column 25
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for org.eclipse.birt.chart.device.swt:org.eclipse.birt.chart.device.swt:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${project.basedir}/lib/org.eclipse.birt.chart.device.swt_4.6.0.v201606072122.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 100, column 25
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for org.eclipse.birt.chart.engine.extension:org.eclipse.birt.chart.engine.extension:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${project.basedir}/lib/org.eclipse.birt.chart.engine.extension_4.6.0.v201606072122.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 109, column 25
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for org.eclipse.birt.chart.engine:org.eclipse.birt.chart.engine:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${project.basedir}/lib/org.eclipse.birt.chart.engine_4.6.0.v201606072122.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 118, column 25
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for org.eclipse.birt.chart.examples.core:org.eclipse.birt.chart.examples.core_4.6.0.v201606072122.jar:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${project.basedir}/lib/org.eclipse.birt.chart.examples.core_4.6.0.v201606072122.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 127, column 25
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for org.eclipse.birt.chart.ui.extension:org.eclipse.birt.chart.ui.extension:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${project.basedir}/lib/org.eclipse.birt.chart.ui.extension_4.6.0.v201606072122.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 136, column 25
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for org.eclipse.birt.chart.ui:org.eclipse.birt.chart.ui:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${project.basedir}/lib/org.eclipse.birt.chart.ui_4.6.0.v201606072122.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 145, column 25
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for org.eclipse.birt.core.ui:org.eclipse.birt.core.ui:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${project.basedir}/lib/org.eclipse.birt.core.ui_4.6.0.v201606072122.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 154, column 25
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for org.eclipse.birt.core:org.eclipse.birt.core:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${project.basedir}/lib/org.eclipse.birt.core_4.6.0.v201606072122.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 163, column 25
[WARNING]
```

Part of my pom.xml:

```
<properties>
        <birt.version>4.6.0-20160607</birt.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.birt.runtime/org.eclipse.birt.runtime -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</artifactId>
        <version>${birt.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.chart.device.extension</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.birt.chart.device.extension</artifactId>
        <version>${birt.version}</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/org.eclipse.birt.chart.device.extension_4.6.0.v201606072122.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.chart.device.pdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.birt.chart.device.pdf</artifactId>
        <version>${birt.version}</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/org.eclipse.birt.chart.device.pdf_4.6.0.v201606072122.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.chart.device.svg</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.birt.chart.device.svg</artifactId>
        <version>${birt.version}</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/org.eclipse.birt.chart.device.svg_4.6.0.v201606072122.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.chart.chart-viewer</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.birt.chart.chart-viewer</artifactId>
        <version>${birt.version}</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/chart-viewer.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.chart.device.swt</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.birt.chart.device.swt</artifactId>
        <version>${birt.version}</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/org.eclipse.birt.chart.device.swt_4.6.0.v201606072122.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.chart.engine.extension</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.birt.chart.engine.extension</artifactId>
        <version>${birt.version}</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/org.eclipse.birt.chart.engine.extension_4.6.0.v201606072122.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.chart.engine</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.birt.chart.engine</artifactId>
        <version>${birt.version}</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/org.eclipse.birt.chart.engine_4.6.0.v201606072122.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.chart.examples.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.birt.chart.examples.core_4.6.0.v201606072122.jar</artifactId>
        <version>${birt.version}</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/org.eclipse.birt.chart.examples.core_4.6.0.v201606072122.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.chart.ui.extension</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.birt.chart.ui.extension</artifactId>
        <version>${birt.version}</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/org.eclipse.birt.chart.ui.extension_4.6.0.v201606072122.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.chart.ui</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.birt.chart.ui</artifactId>
        <version>${birt.version}</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/org.eclipse.birt.chart.ui_4.6.0.v201606072122.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId> org.eclipse.birt.core.ui</groupId>
        <artifactId> org.eclipse.birt.core.ui</artifactId>
        <version>${birt.version}</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/org.eclipse.birt.core.ui_4.6.0.v201606072122.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.birt.core</artifactId>
        <version>${birt.version}</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/org.eclipse.birt.core_4.6.0.v201606072122.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>    
</dependencies>
```